Boot is stuck at: FIPS check done
After enabling FIPS and seeing the -fips named vmlinuz kernel image, my boot sequence is hung at "FIPS check done" .  Is there anything to do here?

It's the highest security standard, system won't boot at all. :) Joking aside, I'd suggest entering GRUB, selecting the default boot entry, hitting C and manually edit the kernel parameters removing fips=1, then press F10 to boot. That should get you at least to your desktop / TTY. As to what's causing this, someone else should chime in.

Does this occur every reboot, or every other reboot?
